# user-controlled for loop iteration in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, user-input

I am new to the world of Python, and I have searched numerous places for a way to overcome a problem I'm having.

First, some context so as to be as clear as possible.  I have created a (decent-sized) dictionary of CAN data messages.  The CAN message IDs serve as keys, while each message is paired in a list with its corresponding timestamp.  The result is a dictionary with a format like the one below (but much larger):

```
d = {'1011C0BB': [[30.1429, '0FFF0000']],
    '00132058': [[30.1942, '00'], [30.2512, '00'], [40.5021, '00]]
```

...and so on.  The gist being that the dictionary has a bunch of keys, all of which have lists of lists of data, with those lists being of variable length.

I am trying to visualize how the bits are changing over time so that I can attempt to reverse engineer their meaning (or at least their groupings).  I have achieved bitwise point-by-point plotting of the data with the following code:

```
colors = list(product(np.arange(0.00,1.00,0.20),repeat=3))
rgb = 0

for i in range(0,len(rawdata_dct.keys())):
    plt.hold(True)
    plt.figure(i)
    plt.title(rawdata_dct.keys()[i])
    for j in range(0,len(rawdata_dct.values()[i])):
        timedata = []
        timedata.append(rawdata_dct.values()[i][j][0])
        for k in range(0,len(rawdata_dct.values()[i][j][1])):
            bitdata = []
            bitdata.append(int(rawdata_dct.values()[i][j][1][k],16))
            for m in range(0,len(bitdata)):
                plt.plot(timedata, bitdata[m], marker='o', 
                        color=[colors[rgb][0],colors[rgb][1],colors[rgb][2]],
                        label=rawdata_dct.keys()[i])
            del bitdata
        del timedata
    rgb += 1
```

It's probably not the cleanest or most Pythonic way of doing that, but it works and it color-codes the data in correspondence with the CAN ID (the original intent was to produce one graph with all of the data, but that's not an effective way of looking at it)

My main issue is that it produces a huge amount of graphs (or one graph with a huge amount of colorful data on it with some slight alterations).  I was hoping to find a way to control the iterations of the outermost loop with user input.  The end goal is that the script populates the first graph, and then waits for user input (say, pressing 'Space') before populating the next graph.  How might I achieve that?

Comment: Input makes the program wait until an input is submitted so you could just add a line like `filler = input("Press enter:")` and it will wait till the user hits enter to continue.

Comment: That seems to have worked, although the figure windows keep freezing.  However, when I press enter, it keeps making new windows, so the control of the iteration is working.